# How to prevent Gradle from changing the dependency version of a library to a later one, because another lib requires it as a transitive dependency?

Tags: android, gradle, okhttp

**Context**

I am trying to include the [Flipper debug tool](https://github.com/facebook/flipper) into my app with the Network plugin. In order for this to be useful, I need to add a Flipper Network interceptor in my HTTP module, which provides an an OkHttp client for my app to use. I only include the Flipper libraries in debug configurations. I include Flipper deps in my http module like this:

```
dependencies {
[...]
    debugImplementation dep('com.facebook.flipper:flipper')
    debugImplementation dep('com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin')
}
```

**The problem**

The issue I face is that [Flipper transitively depends on `okhttp:3.14.1'`](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/blob/0dd7c277d4a176043cb534cacbc71a727f66159a/build.gradle#L90) and our app supports clients up to API level 16. Now the issue is that, [below API 21 (Lolipop) I can't use any version of okhttp above 3.12.x.](https://developer.squareup.com/blog/okhttp-3-13-requires-android-5/)

Because of this, other things that depend on OkHttp, start using a version of `OkHttp` above 8.12.x, which makes the initialization of HTTP break.

```
11-08 13:48:28.394 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects
        at okhttp3.CertificatePinner.withCertificateChainCleaner(CertificatePinner.java:231)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:238)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:202)
```

Looking at the dependency tree, it seems to me that beacuse Flipper requires version 3.14.1 of OkHttp, other parts of my app that need an OkHttp client in the debug configuration are also using 3.14.1 instead of 3.12.3:

```
debugAndroidTest
[...]
+--- project :libs:http-retrofit
|    +--- project :libs:http (*)
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.3 -> 3.14.1 (*)
|    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0 -> 3.14.1 (*)
```

**How can I make Gradle not change the dependency version of OkHTTP everywhere else?**

EDIT Clarification:

Basically I want all my Gradle dependencies that depend on OkHttp to use version 3.12.3 (regardless of Android API version), except for Flipper which I only include in Debug builds, which should be able to have version 3.14.1 if it really needs to.

Answer (score 2):

From the [dependency constraints](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html) gradle guide:

> Dependency constraints allow you to define the version or the version
>   range of both dependencies declared in the build script and transitive dependencies.

And the [Declaring Rich Versions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/rich_versions.html) guide:

> strictly
>   Any version not matched by this version notation will be excluded. This is the strongest version declaration. On a declared dependency, a strictly can downgrade a version. When on a transitive dependency, it will cause dependency resolution to fail if no version acceptable by this clause can be selected. See overriding dependency version for details. This term supports dynamic versions.
>
> When defined, overrides previous require declaration and clears previous reject.

So putting this together, I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
dependencies {
[...]
    debugImplementation dep('com.facebook.flipper:flipper')
    debugImplementation dep('com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin')

    constraints {
        debugImplementation dep('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp') {
            version {
                strictly '3.12.3'
            }
    }
}
```

Of course, if one of the dependencies **can't** work with version 3.12.3 then it will simply fail to resolve the constraints.

Comment: Hey @NickRundle, thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, that locks all dependencies of OkHttp in my app to version 3.12.3. I will try to play around with your suggestion nonetheless, as it might be part of the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe gradle [ResolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) might be useful for this. You can force your http module to use a specific version of okhttp like:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
     // force certain versions of dependencies (including transitive)
     //  *append new forced modules:
     force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.3'
    }
}
```

Although not sure if forcing this dep will break Flipper debug tool. You can play with different resolution strategies to see if it solves your issue.